# C++ char array with stdin

Tags: c++, arrays, string, pointers, sizeof

I am trying to get the size of an array populated by stdin:

```
char *myArray;
cin >> myArray
cout << sizeof(myArray);
```

This returns 4 when I enter a string greater with a length greater than 4 e.g. "40905898"

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: sizeof() is a COMPILER time directive. It will evaluate to a fixed constant at compile time in this case the size of the pointer.

Answer (score 11):

`sizeof` operator statically evaluates to the size of the thing you are passing to it. A `char*` is a pointer which, depending on the machine architecture has a specific size (4 bytes on 32 bit systems and 8 bytes on 64 bit machines). To accomplish what you are trying to do, I suggest you use the `string` type which you can use by adding `#include <string>` along with `using namespace std;` to your source file.

```
string line;
cin >> line;
cout << line.length() << endl;
```

It's less error prone and easier to use.

By the way, the thing you've tried to do is really dangerous. In fact, when you use `cin >> myArray`, you should have already allocated some memory for `myArray` which you haven't done. This will cause memory corruption which might crash your program and possibly put it to buffer overrun attacks.

A simple array in C++ has no idea about its size. You can use `sizeof` **only if the array is statically allocated** and you are using `sizeof` on the array itself, not another pointer to it, for example this won't work as you might expect:

```
int x[5];
int *a = &x[0];
// a[i] is now the same as x[i] but:
cout << sizeof(x) << endl; // prints 20, assuming int is 32 bits long
cout << sizeof(a) << endl; // prints 4, assuming a pointer is 32 bits long
```

Note that the total size of the array is printed on the first line, not the element count. You can use `sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x)` to find out element count in static arrays. This thing is not possible for dynamically allocated arrays using `new`. In fact C++ arrays are very error prone and you should take extreme care when working with them and you'd better use `vector` and `string` in most cases instead.

Answer (score 2):

sizeof(pointer) will always return 4. You want to use strlen().

Edit: IIRC, sizeof is evaluated at compile time, it only cares about the type, not the content.

Comment: You assume a 32-bit CPU.  On a 64-bit CPU it'll return 8.

Comment: @csl it will return 4 on 64 bit CPUs if you compile it as 32 bit ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is because myArray is a pointer that occupies 4 bytes. If you want to get the length of your string, use strlen or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have lots of problems here:

myArray is not initialised - where is the input going to live?

You usually use: cin >> myArray;  (Note the direction of the chevrons and the semi-colon)

sizeof(myArray) will always return the same value (4 on your platform)

Try this version instead:

```
char* myArray= new char[50];
cin >> myArray;
cout << myArray;
cout << strlen(myArray);
```

Its not without its own problems (I should have deleted myArray), so you should try the answers here that use `string myArray`

Comment: Well, that's right - that's what you'd do if you were calling a function.  I was testing this in main(), so it was cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using sizeof() on a pointer, which is 4 bytes on your 32-bit computer:

```
printf("Pointer size: %d\n", sizeof(void*));
```

If your array is a null-terminated string (the last element being a zero-byte, or '\0'), then you can use

```
strlen(myArray)
```

to get the number of elements (minus one).  E.g.:

```
myArray = "Hello, world!";
printf("Number of characters: %d\n", strlen(myArray));
```

You could also use a statically allocated array, like this:

```
 char array[128];
 printf("sizeof(array) = %d\n", sizeof(array));
 // prints 128
```

Answer (score 0):

As others said, myArray is a pointer.

But why wouldn't you use `std::string`?  You won't need to do the buffer allocation yourself, which you do wrongly in your example (pointer `myArray` points to nothing)

```
std::string myValue;
std::cin >> myValue;
std::cout << myValue.length();
```

If needed, you can get to a pointer representation of the string by using `string::c_str()`.

Answer (score 0):

As others said `sizeof` returns the size of the object passed to it, in the case of a pointer it's the size of the pointer. `sizeof` does *not* follow the pointer to see what size the object it points to is (how can it know it could point to one `char` or to an array there's not good way to know).

Additionally when you read from `cin` you have to allocate some space into which the data must be read, `cin` will not allocate space for you. You can allocate space either on the stack or the heap:

```
char stack_line[1024]; // This will overflow if more than 1024 chars are needed
char heap_line*  = new char[1024]; // ditto
```

The thing to note here is that `sizeof(stack_line) == 1024` while `sizeof(heap_line) == 4` <sup>[on 32 bit machines]</sup> so you must be careful when using the `sizeof` operator.

In practice it's better to use an `std::string` which knows how to allocate the space itself.

Answer (score 0):

well if you *were* going to use sizeof(myArray), you should've done sizeof(*myArray); because with pointers, no star is the address not the value.
Like this:

```
char *myArray;
cin >> *myArray;
cout << *myArray;
```